# default username and password for ubuntu12.04 LTS image

Tags: 12.04, password

I have spawned an OpenStack instance using ubuntu 12.04 image that I got from http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/precise/current/precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img.

Its now asking me for a username and password. I haven't set any username or password during the process. I have tried username to be "ubuntu" and password as bland and "ubuntu". Both dont seem to work.

Can someone please help me out? Its urgent.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to connect directly to an instance with the keypair you have used, when you booted the instance. Try:

> ssh -i /your_keypair\ root@/ip\

(don't forget to chmod 700 your keypair, or you won't be able to use it)

---

Other option is to get a testing cirros image up and running it has credentials:

> Username: cirros 
>   Password: cubswin:) (with that smiley)

There is a how-to with a link for cirros image here:
[Registering Virtual Machine Images](http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/openstack-compute/install/yum/content/uploading-to-glance.html)